Confusion Around useRouter() for shallow routing
I'm quite confused about the behavior of useRouter() in Next.js, specifically with the push and replace methods.
My goal is to update the URL parameters as soon as my input changes.
To achieve this, I revisited the Next.js docs and found an example for setting new searchParams using the useRouter hook like this:
router.push('/?counter=10', undefined, { shallow: true })

The key part here is the shallow option, as I wanted to avoid a full page reload. However, I soon realized that this option has been removed in the Next.js App Router, without any clear replacement. So, I was back to square one without a solution.
Afterward, I came across a section in the Next.js docs that provided an example for updating searchParams like this:
router.push(pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'asc'))

However, after implementing this, I found several articles and sources saying it’s not recommended to use router for changing URL parameters, as it can trigger a refetch and cause a full reload of the page. You can see this mentioned in the Next.js docs and also in various articles.
Here’s where things got strange: Although the Next.js docs say router.push will cause refetching and reloading, I didn’t observe any of that in my logs. I used a useEffect without a dependency array to check if my Navlinks component would rerender when another component (with the input) was using router.push, but it didn't:
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("rerender Navlinks");
});

It seemed to work, but the updates to the URL bar were laggy and slow when updating the search parameters. So, even though I couldn't confirm a full reload, there was definitely something odd happening, which I couldn't pinpoint.
As an alternative, I tried:
window.history.replaceState(null, "", pathname + '?' + createQueryString('sort', 'asc'));

Interestingly, this was much more responsive in the URL bar and didn’t feel as sluggish. It worked fine, but I don’t understand why this method performs better than router.replace. I couldn't figure out why router.replace was slower.
Of course, I could have simplified things by using Nuqs, but constantly adding new packages to solve problems doesn't help in the long run and could slow down the app by increasing bundle size. I wanted to debug this to better understand the root issue, but I’m still unsure why router.replace and router.push felt laggy in the URL bar, even though the input itself was always responsive.
Does anyone have insights on why this is happening or can share best practices for handling this?
Here’s the code for reference:
"use client";

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { usePathname, useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input";

export default function Search() {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);

  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const search = searchParams.get("search") || "";

  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState(search);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rerender");
  });

  // Get a new searchParams string by merging the current
  // searchParams with a provided key/value pair
  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString());
      params.set(name, value);

      return params.toString();
    },
    [searchParams]
  );

  const handleInputChange = (word: string) => {
    const newPath = pathname + "?" + createQueryString("search", word);
    // Next js router
    router.replace(
      newPath,
      undefined
      // { shallow: true,} // This is no longer supported
    );
    // Vanilla JS history API
    window.history.replaceState(null, "", newPath);
    setSearchText(word);
  };

  // API Call on search
  useEffect(() => {
    const awaitFunc = async (value: string) => {
      const data: any = await apiFunction(value);
      if (!data) {
        setEntries([]);
        return;
      }
      setEntries(data);
    };

    if (search) {
      awaitFunc(search);
    } else {
      setEntries([]);
    }
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Input
        value={searchText}
        onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target.value)}
      />
      {JSON.stringify(entries)}
    </div>
  );
}

